# Why is the preview in SCP working, but the actual classification not?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, classification, scp

I am using the Semi-automatic Classification Plugin (SCP) to classify Sentinel and Landsat satellite imagery. I have training ROIs saved in a file (.scp) and (re)calculated their spectral signatures. When I calculate the preview of the classification, it works fine. However, when I try to run the actual classification for the whole image (using the 'Apply mask' option) the algorithm starts running but no output is actually created.

I have included an image which shows the satellite imagery (background), the masking polygon, the ROIs (black polygons) and the preview (raster in center of image). If I run the algorithm without the mask, QGIS crashes (probably because the satellite imagery is too large).

[image]

Any ideas how I can solve this?